# How to write a statement by declaring variables and passing them into the statement using cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to write a "Neo4j" statement in "Cypher" to create a node. All I want to do is that I want to declare some variables, assign a value to them and pass those into the statement instead of assigning values directly in the statement. I have listed down the working statement and my desired format of the statement below. Any help would be appreciated.

**My working statement:**

```
    CREATE (n:Customers {Name:"Bharath" , GoestoRetailer: "Prestige 
    Store"})
    WITH n
    MATCH(c:Customers) 
    WITH c 
    MATCH (r:Retailer) WHERE r.StartTime = "9:00 AM" and  r.Name 
    contains c.GoestoRetailer
    CREATE (r)-[:NineDelivery]->(c)
```

**Required statement format:**

```
    // Declaration of variables
    WITH cName = "Bharath" as cName
    WITH rName = "Prestige Store" as rName
    WITH openingTime = "9:00 AM" as openingTime
    CREATE (n:Customers {Name: cName, GoestoRetailer: rName})
    WITH n.CustomerName = cName
    WITH n
    MATCH(c:Customers) 
    WITH c 
    //Condition
    MATCH (r:Retailer) WHERE r.StartTime = openingTime  and  r.Name 
    contains c.GoestoRetailer
    //Action
    CREATE (r)-[:NineDelivery]->(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply use WITH like:

```
WITH "Bharath" as cName, "Prestige Store" as rName, "9:00 AM" as openingTime
CREATE (n:Customers {Name: cName, GoestoRetailer: rName})
(...)
```

Comment: @bharry29 Also take a look at documentation on [parameters in neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/), which is the recommended way to do this when it's not just a one-off query via the browser.